# Proving a group of order 343 is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, simple-groups, p-groups

Hi I need help with proving a group of order 343 is not simple. Since a group of order 343 is a 7-group, I believe the proof will involve the use of G's nontrivial center and class equation. I am just not sure how to start this proof.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, it has a nontrivial centre, which is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Finite $p$-groups are nilpotent. Also, as was pointed out above, the center of a group is always normal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem

Comment: Note that the center being normal is not enough, since it can be equal to $G$. Of course if $Z(G)=G$ then it is easy to prove that $G$ is not simple, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every group $G$ we have $Z(G)\trianglelefteq G$. Here as we know $Z(G)\ne\{e\}$. So if $Z(G)\ne G$ then $G$ has a non trivial normal subgroup and hence is not simple. If $Z(G)=G$ then $G$ is abelian. In that case each subgroup of $G$ is normal in it. By Cauchy's theorem $G$ has a subgroup of order $7$, and this is a non trivial normal subgroup. Again, $G$ is not simple.

Answer (score 1):

Well $343= 7^3$ and it is a well known fact that the only simple $p$-groups are the cyclic $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. To prove this just look to the class equation
$$
|G|= |Z(G)| + \sum_{i} |G : C_G(g_i)|
$$
that becomes in our case
$$
p^n = |Z(G)| + \sum_i p^{k_i}
$$
with $k_i \geq 1$  unless $n=1$. Therefore $p$ divides $|Z(G)|$ and $G$ has nontrivial center.